# Can't remove underline from link

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div in an anchor tag and I am trying to remove the blue underline from the link.

```css
.removelinkdefault {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="/user/reillylawless23"><div class="removelinkdefault">Reilly Lawless</div></a>
```

All documentation I have seen says to use `text-decoration: none;` however it does not appear to be working:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the `class="removelinkdefault"` to the link (`a`) instead of the div

```css
.removelinkdefault {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="/user/reillylawless23" class="removelinkdefault"><div>Reilly Lawless</div></a>
```

Also, now you don't need `!important`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the underline from the anchor element rather than the `div`:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Links are the  `<a>` tag, not the  `<div>`

```css
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="/user/reillylawless23"><div class="removelinkdefault">Reilly Lawless</div></a>
```